# mod_rewrite rewrite rule is not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have confirmed with my host that mod_rewrite is enabled. I want incoming requests to be rewritten to be passed to a mod_rewrite.php file in my root directory. Mod_rewrite does not seem to be working at all. Here is the code in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /mod_rewrite.php?vpath=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the slash after `^`? I thought no leading slash was present in the URL data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ mod_rewrite.php?vpath=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
```